# How can I access the column name in the file upload file with c# jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a location project. I need to reach the name of a column in Excel (For example Address) with jquery. How can I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYAcs.png)

Note: I wrote the project in c # mvc. I use axios for the location.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with jquery, do it on the server

Comment: I can catch it on the server. But if the latitude and longitude information is empty in excel, it is necessary to perform operations according to the address column in excel.